# Akka control threadpool threads

Tags: scala, actor, akka

Potentially a very silly question--

Is it possible to customize Akka/Scala actors such that you control the threads that are used by the actors? e.g. can you initialize your own set of threads to be used in the thread pool, or otherwise control/modify the threads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Akka, the thread pool is managed via a MessageDispatcher instance. You can set the dispatcher you want to actors easily:

```
class MyActor( dispatcher: MessageDispatcher ) extends Actor {
  self.dispatcher = dispatcher
  ...
}
```

To provide your own dispatcher, you can extend `akka.dispatch.MessageDispatcher` (see existing dispatchers implementation for examples). Here you can play directly with the threads.

Of course, it's dangerous to put business logic inside a dispatcher because it may break the actor model and increase the number of concurrency bugs...

Answer (score -1):

I tried to understand it myself, but seams that guys in Akka don't want thread management to be exposed to public.

**ThreadPoolConfig** - the class that is responsible for creation of **ExecutorService** instances is a case class with method createExecutorService() declared **final**!

```
  final def createExecutorService(threadFactory: ThreadFactory): ExecutorService = {
    flowHandler match {
      case Left(rejectHandler) ⇒
        val service = new ThreadPoolExecutor(...)
        service
      case Right(bounds) ⇒
        val service = new ThreadPoolExecutor(...)
        new BoundedExecutorDecorator(service, bounds)
    }
  }
```

So, I don't see an easy ways to provide your own ExecutorService.

Comment: This is not correct, you can write your own MessageDispatcher (extend the trait) implementation and pass it to the Actors as in the answer by paradigmatic. In the MessageDispatcher implementation you can choose to use any executorservice you would like. The method you mention is only used from the ExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher.

Comment: How can I do this if MessageDispatcher trait has something like this

    **private[akka] def dispatch(invocation: MessageInvocation): Unit**

Comment: @Raymond Roestenburg
    **private[akka] def start(): Unit**
As I understand this is package private method and cannod be accessed outside akka.